# Unversioned files keep reappearing after checkout

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am puzzled by this and could not find an answer after thoroughly searching Google and StackOverflow.

Basically, I have a repo with 2 branches: master and dev.

When I visit github.com, "master" branch is empty, which is should be.
The dev branch has about 200MB of files, which it should have.

When I move back to the command line and checkout locally (doing `git checkout master`), the folder on my local drive contains a bunch of empty folders from the dev branch. These folders contain only the `.DS_Store` files used by OSX... I have added `.DS_Store` to my `.gitignore` file but the folders keep re-appearing.

Additionally, when I perform `git clean -d -f -x .` on the master branch, it actually tells me that it's removing all the unversioned folders, which is good! The folders then also disappear from my local drive. HOWEVER, after checking out the dev branch again, and then check out the master branch again, the unversioned folders reappear on my local git repo.

I have no clue how to resolve this and to avoid git from re-creating the unversioned folders each time I check out the master branch. I am truly lost on this one!

Comment: Did you commit the .DS_Store folders sometime before adding them to the .gitignore?

Comment: That's possible yes... However these files do not appear on github.com

Comment: What happens if you try doing 'git rm *.DS_Store', follwoed by a commit+push?

Comment: Nothing (fatal: pathspec '*.DS_Store' did not match any files) and I think it makes sense since the files are not under version control? Still, the empty folders keep re-appearing

Comment: I'm betting OSX has an indexing service watching for changes and keeping its notes in that file.